# How to use a single Play Store account to purchase same subscription in different in-app accounts?

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription, google-play-billing

I have implemented a login feature in my app where a user can pay for subscription and have that subscription tied to their in-app login account by using the setObfuscatedAccoundId() method. However, in a scenario where the current user(user_A) makes a purchase, logs out of the app and a different user_B logs in, user_B is unable to purchase the same subscription as it has already been bought by user_A (as they share the same underlying Google Play account) even though I DON'T want these in-app accounts to be related at all. Currently, what happens is user_B gets a responses that states "You already own this item". So that makes me wonder:

1. Can we actually possibly use a single/the same underlying Play Store account to purchase the same subscription while logging in to an app with different user accounts?
2. Also, what would be an ideal design approach for a problem like this considering the limitation?

I am still a beginner at this and would really appreciate your inputs!

Comment: The Google account is the in-app account and a subscription cannot be purchased twice, your design must be based on this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Hi, I understand that this is a non-programming question but since it is related to app development and since I am not able to get answers else where, I thought it might be worth asking here as well.

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/?hl=en#topic=3364260 - There are 2 links at the bottom of the page: *Ask the community* and *Contact support*. Alternatively - maybe - you could ask that on https://superuser.com/ - make sure to check the help section and see if your question fits there.

Answer (score -1):

I'm beginner at this like you and may I was wrong but I think you can not do that because the subscriptions are saved in your google account and you can not buy same subscription you owned already.